# A problem with a function that changes classes names

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this function that changes a class name to another if a button is clicked and then I have other function that gets that changed classes name and receives that element with the class changed, but im getting undefined instead of the element im looking for and I don't know why. Besides I want to ask you guys if its possible to in local storage add items with the key superior to the highest I got, imagine I have one item there with (1,"John"), and the next one I had has the key 2 ?
Html:

```
<button id="xs" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)"
  class="unclicked_size_button"><b>XS</b></button>
<button id="s" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)"
  class="unclicked_size_button"><b>S</b></button>
<button id="m" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)"
  class="unclicked_size_button"><b>M</b></button>
<button id="l" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)"
  class="unclicked_size_button"><b>L</b></button>
<button id="xl" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)"
  class="unclicked_size_button"><b>XL</b></button>
```

Javascript:

```js
function SizeButtonStyle(el) {
  var size = el;

  if (el.id == "xs") {
    document.getElementById("xs").className = "clicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("s").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("m").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("l").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("xl").className = "unclicked_size_button";
  }
  if (el.id == "s") {
    document.getElementById("xs").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("s").className = "clicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("m").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("l").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("xl").className = "unclicked_size_button";
  }
  if (el.id == "m") {
    document.getElementById("xs").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("s").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("m").className = "clicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("l").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("xl").className = "unclicked_size_button";
  }
  if (el.id == "l") {
    document.getElementById("xs").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("s").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("m").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("l").className = "clicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("xl").className = "unclicked_size_button";
  }
  if (el.id == "xl") {
    document.getElementById("xs").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("s").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("m").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("l").className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById("xl").className = "clicked_size_button";
  }
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
  var product = document.getElementsByClassName("product_name")[0].innerText;
  var price = document.getElementsByClassName("price")[0].innerText;
  var info = [product, "XS", price];
  console.log(info);
  localStorage.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(info));
}
```

Comment: Which element access attempt is causing an undefined error, specifically? You have `product_name` and `price` class names, but no HTML that uses them.

Comment: The “unclicked_size_button” ones

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing incorrect about the button class changing code, the unmodified JavaScript below works with no errors.

Please include more specific details of the actual error you are encountering.

```js
function SizeButtonStyle(el) {

  var size = el

  if (el.id == 'xs') {
    document.getElementById('xs').className = "clicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('s').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('m').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('l').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('xl').className = "unclicked_size_button";


  }
  if (el.id == 's') {
    document.getElementById('xs').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('s').className = "clicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('m').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('l').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('xl').className = "unclicked_size_button";
  }
  if (el.id == 'm') {
    document.getElementById('xs').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('s').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('m').className = "clicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('l').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('xl').className = "unclicked_size_button";
  }
  if (el.id == 'l') {
    document.getElementById('xs').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('s').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('m').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('l').className = "clicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('xl').className = "unclicked_size_button";
  }
  if (el.id == 'xl') {
    document.getElementById('xs').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('s').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('m').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('l').className = "unclicked_size_button";
    document.getElementById('xl').className = "clicked_size_button";
  }
}
```

```css
.unclicked_size_button {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.clicked_size_button {
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="xs" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="unclicked_size_button"><b>XS</b></button>
<button id="s" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="unclicked_size_button"><b>S</b></button>
<button id="m" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="unclicked_size_button"><b>M</b></button>
<button id="l" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="unclicked_size_button"><b>L</b></button>
<button id="xl" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="unclicked_size_button"><b>XL</b></button>
```

Comment: the problem is that my document.getElementbyclassname('clicked_size_button') doesn't work

Comment: The code you provided does not contain `document.getElementsByClassName('clicked_size_button')`, making it very hard to diagnose your problem.